# ruby: Translate thai datetime string to datetime object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, internationalization, thai

I want to parse this Thai date: `"15 พ.ค. 2017 12:30"` into a `DateTime` object. How can I achieve this?

What I've found out parsing `November` in different languages:

✅ `DateTime.parse "Novembre" => Wed, 01 Nov 2017 00:00:00 +0000`

✅ `DateTime.parse "Noviembre" => Wed, 01 Nov 2017 00:00:00 +0000`

❌ `DateTime.parse "พฤศจิกายน" => ArgumentError: invalid date`

❌ `DateTime.parse "15 พฤศจิกายน 2017 12:30" => Wed, 15 Mar 2017 12:30:00 +0000`

Edit:
My findings are incorrect. `DateTime#parse` does not translate. See Iceman's comment below.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do I convert a string with a Thai month name into the correct date time object?

Comment: Basically,  I don't understand how i18n works.

Comment: It's also quite likely that support for thai month names is just not implemented. But if you know the names _and_ the format is constant (you know which number means what), then it's trivial to take the string apart and build a Time object via `Time.new`

Comment: Thankyou, @SergioTulentsev. That would make sense. I'll try your recommendation.

Comment: Thai does have an i18n file here https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/th.yml so at least it should be supported in a way.

Comment: @iceman Correct. This is helpful for rendering a Date object to a translated string.
`I18n.l DateTime.now, :locale => :th => "15 มีนาคม 2017 10:05"`

Comment: It seems it's not parsing anything except English. The reason `Novembre` and `Noviembre` work is just because they start with `Nov`. `DateTime.parse 'Novsense'` also returns `01 Nov`. So it seems Thai is not the problem but just any language except English.

Comment: Ah, I see. Makes sense. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

This monkey patch to the Date class was very useful and solved my issue:
https://gist.github.com/jackrg/2927162

add this line:

```
MONTH_TRANSLATIONS.merge! make_hash(%w/ม.ค. ก.พ. มี.ค. เม.ย. พ.ค. มิ.ย. ก.ค. ส.ค. ก.ย. ต.ค. พ.ย. ธ.ค./) # thai abbreviated
```

Answer (score -2):

I think maybe months in Thai start form different a number than in others places in the world. So you can add one more month:

```
"15 เม.ย. 2017 12:30".to_datetime + 1.month
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't the case. If I try to convert another month from Thai, it still returns a date object with the month of March(the current month).
`"15 พ.ค. 2017 12:30".to_datetime
=> Wed, 15 Mar 2017 12:30:00 +0000`